# How to search for document in Sharepoint

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I am trying to create a document library search crawler depending on the document library I have created in c#.

```
            using (ClientContext context = new ClientContext(SiteURL))
            {
                SecureString securestring = new SecureString();
                SPPassword.ToCharArray().ToList().ForEach(s => securestring.AppendChar(s));
                context.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(SPUser, securestring);
                Web web = context.Web;
                context.Load(web);
                List list = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(libraryName);
                CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
                camlQuery.ViewXml = "";

                ListItemCollection listItemCollection = list.GetItems(camlQuery);
                context.Load(listItemCollection);

                foreach (var item in listItemCollection)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(item.DisplayName);
                }
            }
```

but I failed to display the document name.

Answer (score 0):

Check with ViewFileds for required column

```
<ViewFields>
   <FieldRef Name='ID' />
   <FieldRef Name='LinkFilename' />
   <FieldRef Name='FileDirRef' />
</ViewFields>
```